# Referencing jars in jnlp file

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have the below JNLP file. I have created the appropriate folders, when the jnlp file downloads, message the system cannot find the specified path is seen at the console.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.5" codebase="http://localhost:8080/myapp/jars">
    <information>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <vendor>MyApp</vendor>

    </information>
    <resources>
    <jar href="main.jar"/>
    <jar href="jcalendar.jar"/>
    <jar href="apps/jdi.jar"/>
    <jar href="JGo.jar"/>
 </resources>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <application-desc main-class="com.myapp.jars.Main">

    </application-desc>

</jnlp>
```

```
Java Web Start 1.6.0_22
Using JRE version 1.6.0_22-b04 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\
<----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
```

### 0-5: set trace level to

/myapps/jars/main.jar
/myapps/jars/jcalendar.jar
\myapps\jars\apps\jdi.jar(The system cannot find the path specified)
/myapps/jars/jGo.jar

I have the jars signed, and placed them under the folder jars/apps/jdo.jar

Could some one help me.

Thanks, 
Karthik

When I include along with other jars within jars folder, the console throws Unable to load the resource file (jdi.jar)

```
com.sun.deploy.net.FailedDownloadException: Unable to load resource: http://localhost:8080/myapp/jars/jdi.jar
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.actionDownload(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResourceCacheEntry(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.DownloadEngine.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.LaunchDownload$DownloadTask.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the missing jar really in a folder called `apps` at http://localhost:8080/myapp/jars/apps/jdi.jar ?   If `jdi.jar` is in same place as other jars, try:

```
<jar href="jdi.jar"/>
```

Comment: When I use the whole url, it prompts me to open/save the jdi.jar. As suggested, when I place the jar along with other, launch error, Unable to load the resource file.

Comment: The jar file needs some modification, and it is not a jnlp issue more. Used the debugger option and found out the problem. Used property to webstart/true. All worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @Kaygee can you please elaborate?